# C++ structure and vector

Tags: c++, vector, structure

What does it mean:

```
L[a].push_back(edge(b, c));
```

L - vector of structure edge:

```
vector<edge> L[1000];
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The [documentation for `std::vector<T>::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is fairly explanatory.

Comment: Why L[a]? What diference between L.push_back and L[a].push_back? May be you know how to write the same on C#?

Comment: @R.I. In C# this would be `L[a].Add(new Edge(b, c))`. `L` would be `List<Edge>[] L = new List<Edge>[1000]` with individual elements filled with `new List<Edge>()`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand)

Comment: @R.I. you know `L` is an *array* of `vector<edge>` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start parsing this statement from the back, and figure it out step by step:

- `edge(b, c)` makes a new `edge` by calling its constructor
- `push_back(edge(b, c))` appends a copy of the newly created `edge` to the `vector`
- `L[a]` takes a `vector at index`a`from the array of vectors`L`

Overall, this means "add a new `edge` to `vector<edge>` at index `a` of the array `L[]`"

Answer (score 0):

L is not a vector of edge, it is an array of vectors of edge. `[1000]` does not refer to the vector size but rather to the array size. So `L[a].push_back(edge(b, c));` means you push back an edge to the a'th vector of the array.